# vector iterators incompatible while erase from vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator, erase

I have a map which elements are vectors.I have to delete from these vectors all elements which are equal to special number `num`

```
std::map<size_t,std::vector<size_t> > myMap;
for (std::map<size_t,std::vector<size_t> >::iterator itMap = myMap.begin();itMap != myMap.end();++itMap )
{
    for (std::vector<size_t>::iterator itVec = itMap->second.begin();itVec != itMap->second.end();)
    {
        auto itNextVec = itVec;
        ++itNextVec;
        if (*itVec == num)
        {
            itMap->second.erase(itVec );
        }
        itVec = itNextVec;
    }
}
```

The code causes run-time exepssion .In VS - `vector iterators incompatible`.
Can someone point what is the cause for that?

Thanks

Comment: You know about [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), right? It wouldn't just be prettier, it would be more efficient. `auto& v = itMap->second; v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), num), v.end());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::vector::erase` returns an `iterator` to the next position of the list, and so when you do an erase you should make your iterator equal to the returned value.

The only thing that you have to consider is that the returned `iterator` could be the end so you should check for that.

What I personally like to do is is after doing in an erase and I get the next iterator position, I go back to the previous position of the returned iterator and than call a continue on the `for loop`

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myInt;
    myInt.push_back(1);myInt.push_back(2);myInt.push_back(3);

    for(auto iter = myInt.begin();
        iter != myInt.end();
        ++iter)
    {
        if(*iter == 1)
        {
            iter = myInt.erase(iter);
            if(iter != myInt.begin())
            {
                iter = std::prev(iter);
                continue;
            }
        }

        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But doing an erase inside of a iterator loop is frowned upon because it invalidates the old iterator and that could cause a lot of issues if you didn't plan for them.

Comment: Can you explain me why my approach is not good : I don`t refer or increase itVec after deleting ,but use auto itNextVec to update it

Comment: @Yakov: `erase` doesn't only invalidate the iterator that it was called on, it invalidates every iterator that points to a position after it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - only in vector or in each std container?

Comment: @Yakov: vector and deque. The other containers never invalidate their iterators unless the specific object is erased.

Answer (score 2):

erasing will invalidate the iterator

```
Iterator validity
Iterators, pointers and references pointing to position (or first) and beyond are 
invalidated, with all iterators, pointers and references to elements before position (or 
first) are guaranteed to keep referring to the same elements they were referring to 
before the call.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't trivially erase an item from a collection while iterating over it. Think a little about it, your removing what `itVec` "points" to, after the removal `itVec` no longer "points" to an element, so it no longer have a "next" pointer.

If you check e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), you will see that the `erase` function returns an iterator to the next element. Continue the loop with this one (without increasing it of course).

Comment: But for that reason I hold auto itNextVec

Answer (score 1):

Consider either using a different collection class than `vector` or creating a new vector with the desired items removed rather than removing from existing vector.